# GeoServer WFS OpenLayers EditingPanel Problem

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs, editing

I'm trying to use OpenLayers to edit features of vector data served from a local geoserver. So far, I'm able to pull WMS and WFS layers using OpenLayers from the same geoserver. But now, I'd like enable editing of features of the vector layers. The relevant code section is as shown below:

```
var ke_admin_vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Admin Vector", {
           strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save()],
           protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
               version: "1.1.0",
               url: "http://HOST_IP:port/geoserver/wfs",
               featureType: "ke_admin",
               featureNS: "pop_explorer",
               srsName: "EPSG:4326"
           })
       });

       var editpanel = new EditingPanel(ke_admin_vector)
       map.addControl(editpanel);
```

`ke_admin` is the name of the layer. `pop_explorer` is the workspace url. `EPSG:4326` is the projection of the layer within geoserver.

When I try accessing this from a browser, firebug complains that `EditingPanel is not defined`. Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

ANSWERED.

Comment: Sorry guys. I was following the tutorial at http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/vector/persist.html. As it turns out, the `EditingPanel.js, DeleteFeature.js and editing-panel.css` referenced in the tutorial are available at http://svn.opengeo.org/workshops/projects/openlayers/foss4g_2009/src/extras/. The workshop assumed the learner had downloaded everything.

Comment: So is that resolved then? In which case stick it in as an answer and mark as answered so anyone else who comes across it may avoid a *facepalm* moment :)

Comment: Yes, that answers it. How do I mark a question as answered, if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: You need to post an answer and then mark that as the accepted answer, so just stick your comment into an answer then accept it. Some StackExchangers might say that's not the right thing to do but I think it helps people find the answers quicker if they see that a question has an accepted answer, even if it is your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was following the tutorial at workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/vector/persist.html. As it turns out, the EditingPanel.js, DeleteFeature.js and editing-panel.css referenced in the tutorial are available at http://svn.opengeo.org/workshops/projects/openlayers/foss4g_2009/src/extras/. The workshop assumed the learner had downloaded everything.